# make_heap and sorting x and y co-ordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to get highest co-ordinate `( x, y )`
Following is the code i wrote, is this correct code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct item_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    item_t( int h, int w ) : x(h), y(w) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const item_t& gt) {
        os << "(" << gt.x << "," << gt.y << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
typedef std::vector<item_t> item_list_t;
typedef item_list_t::iterator item_list_itr_t;

struct compare_x_y {
    bool operator ()(const item_t& left, const item_t& right) const {
        return left.x < right.x && left.y < right.y;
    }
};


int main ( int argc, char **argv) { 
    item_list_t items;

    items.push_back(item_t(15, 176));
    items.push_back(item_t(65, 97));
    items.push_back(item_t(72, 43));
    items.push_back(item_t(102, 6));
    items.push_back(item_t(191, 189));
    items.push_back(item_t(90, 163));
    items.push_back(item_t(44, 168));
    items.push_back(item_t(39, 47));
    items.push_back(item_t(123, 37));

    std::make_heap (items.begin(),items.end(),compare_x_y());
    std::cout << "initial max heap   : " << "(" << items.front().x <<"," << items.front().y << ")" << std::endl;


}
```

Is it working for this input but not for other inputs.

Comment: Define 'highest'? Taken literally it means: the coordinate with the biggest Y coordinate. But the way you are comparing them shows both X and Y of one need to be bigger than the X and Y of the other one. But what about comparing (10, 1) and (9, 15)?

Comment: Yes I need to arrange them such that x and y both are greater than previous x and y

Comment: Your definition of highest coordinate is somewhat awkward.  Could you add some examples for which this isn't producing the output you expect?

Comment: I tested this [here](http://ideone.com/8JL8W) and it is working. What do you mean with 'not for other inputs'? What are those 'other inputs'?

Comment: @Avinash according to you definition, in what order should be arranged (0,1) and (1,0)?

Comment: The comparison function is not a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparison function is not a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), and thus using it will give undefined results.

It isn't a strict weak ordering because the equivalence relation is not transitive. For example, (2,2) is equivalent to (4,1), and (4,1) is equivalent to (3,3). But (2,2) is not equivalent to (3,3). (Two values are considered equivalent if neither is less than the other).

You will need to provide another comparison function. Some examples:

- Compare x, and then y if the x values were equal.
- Compare the values of `x+y` for the two points.

Comment: Please fix the typo in your answer. "tranitive" -> "transitive"

Comment: Another option is *compare max(x,y), if equal then compare min(x,y)*. This might be good enough for OP's problem.